# How to read the data store in .txt file which are sparated by comma?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to read the data store in .txt file which are sparated by comma.
StudentList.txt

```
Olivia,SWANSON,F,29001,20
Emma,ONEILL,F,7900,19
```

According to online assitance, I tried the following operations:

```
FILE *fp;
char fname[20];
char sname[20];
char gender[2];
int ID;
int age;
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Catlover\\Desktop\\DSA\\Program2\\StudentList.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    perror("Open fail.");
    exit(1);
    }
while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%s,%d,%d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age) == 5)
{
    printf("%s, %s, %s, %d, %d", fname, sname, gender, ID, age);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

May be I have some wrong understandings about the principle of function `fscanf`

There is nothing output.

Comment: you should check that fp is not null, otherwise there was an error opening the file, and you should generate an error message.

Comment: Changing the question after answers arrive is poor SO etiquette.  Suggest to roll back the code change.

Comment: Sorry, I just try to update the code in order to ensure that I can express what I really mean. Roll back excuted. I will try my best to be a qualified member of Stack Overflow, but it seems I still have a series of rules to learn..

Answer (score 0):

First mistake: You are not checking, whether the file has been opened successfully. `fp` will be 'NULL' if opening failed and any follow up operation will fail if it does.

Second: `%s` consumes every character until the first whitespace character it finds, including the comma. Try `%19[^,],` instead. (Which will stop once it finds a comma).

Comment: Sorry for negligence of opening checking. Do you mean change the fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%s,%d,%d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age) into ("%19[^,]%19[^,]%19[^,]%d,%d", fname, sname, gender, ID, age)

Comment: We all started somewhere, @catlover. I am pointing it out now, so may you avoid running into problems later.

Comment: Not quite. The %19 means: 'Read a maximum of 19 characters', which protects your buffer from overflowing. So your fscanf would thus be: `fscanf("%19[^,],%19[^,],%1[^,],%d,%d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age);`. We also need to remember to actually consume the `,` character.

Comment: I got you, the number ahead of `[^,]` is to make sure no out of bonds happens. Then the output code should be the same as before? Because I have tried your code and it still return nothing.

Comment: The output code looks good. Try putting the result of sscanf into an integer variable and check, how many values it actually managed to read. Use a debugger.

Comment: It seems only stop at the first comma. The debug shows that only the fname receive correct data, the following sname, gender, ID and age all store messy information.

Comment: Please update your code. It's probably just something very small at this point.

Comment: Rather than change code, better to _append_ an update, else the update may invalidate answers.

Comment: Try `%19[^,]` should have been `%19[^,],`, else the comma is not scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Read the *line* of data into a *string* with `fgets()` and then parse.  Use `" %n"` to detect success. `"%n"` records the offset of the scan, if it got that far.  Use `%19[^,],` to read up to 19 non-commas and then a comma.

```
// while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%s,%d,%d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age) == 5) {
//   printf("%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", fname, sname, gender, ID, age);
// }

#define LINE_SIZE 100
char buf[LINE_SIZE];

while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
  // Now parse it
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%19[^,],%19[^,],%1[^,],%d,%d %n", 
    fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age, &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == 0) {
    // Success
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", fname, sname, gender, ID, age);
  } else {
    printf("Trouble with <%s>\n", buf);
  } 
}
```